# Getting filtered autolist

Tags: java, complexity, comparative-review

Is there a better way to write the following code fragment?

I can't have more than 10 conditional statement in my method as it gives cyclomatic complexity.

```
private List<AutoDto> getFilteredAutoList() 
{
    List<AutoDto> autoList = getAutoListForCoverage();
    List<AutoDto> filteredAutoList = new ArrayList<AutoDto>();

    for(AutoDto auto : autoList)
    {
        if("FAQ025".equals((auto.getCarCode()))
                ||"FAQ025".equals((auto.getCarCode()))
                ||"QEF025".equals((auto.getCarCode()))
                ||"QEF037AB".equals((auto.getCarCode()))
                ||"FAQ037AB".equals((auto.getCarCode()))
                ||"FAQ045".equals((auto.getCarCode()))
                ||"QEF045".equals((auto.getCarCode()))
                ||"NBEF028".equals((auto.getCarCode()))
                ||"OPCF028".equals((auto.getCarCode()))
                //20 more OR conditions
                )
        {
            filteredAutoList.add(auto);
        }
    }
    return filteredAutoList;
}
```

The following two approaches came to my mind:

1. **Using `HashSet`**

   ```
   private List<AutoDto> getFilteredAutoList() 
   {
       List<AutoDto> autoList = getAutoListForCoverage();
       List<AutoDto> filteredAutoList = new ArrayList<AutoDto>();

       Set<String> carCodeSet = getCarCodeSet();

       for(AutoDto auto : autoList)
       {
           if(carCodeSet.contains(auto.getCarCode()))
           {
               filteredAutoList.add(auto);
           }
       }
       return filteredAutoList;
   }


   private Set<String> getCarCodeSet()
   {
       Set<String> carCodeSet = new HashSet<String>();

       carCodeSet.add("FAQ025");
       carCodeSet.add("QEF025");
       carCodeSet.add("QEF037AB");
       carCodeSet.add("FAQ037AB");
       carCodeSet.add("FAQ045");
       carCodeSet.add("QEF045");
       carCodeSet.add("NBEF028");
       carCodeSet.add("OPCF028");
       //20 more codes to be added

       return carCodeSet;
   }
   ```
2. **Using `String` `contains` method**

   ```
   private List<AutoDto> getFilteredAutoList1() 
   {
       List<AutoDto> autoList = getAutoListForCoverage();
       List<AutoDto> filteredAutoList = new ArrayList<AutoDto>();

       String carCodeString = "FAQ025,QEF025,QEF037AB,FAQ037AB,FAQ045,QEF045,NBEF028,OPCF028";
       for(AutoDto auto : autoList)
       {
           if(carCodeString.contains(auto.getCarCode()))
           {
               filteredAutoList.add(auto);
           }
       }
       return filteredAutoList;
   }
   ```

Which approach should I follow and why?

Comment: the second solution does something different than the original code. What if I have a car code that is `FAQ02`? That is contained in `FAQ025,Q...`, but it shouldn't count. I would use a static array (define it at the top of the class) and check if the car code is in it.

Comment: Where does that list of codes come from in the first place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why don't you simply use an array of strings, as in:

```
String carCodeSet[] = {"FAQ025","QEF025","QEF037AB", /*...*/ };
```

this seems to me cleaner. Of course the HashSet would have better performance if the list of codes is very long... but maybe for 20 items a linear search on the array is not bad.

The `String.contains` method poses some problems in the fact that you cannot have the separator (comma) in your strings and, more importantly, that any sub-string would match: for example the code "FAQ" would be found as a sub-string. These might not be an issue in your actual use case, but is something which I would prefer not to have in my code.

Comment: `Array` solution looks fine to me. I can check `Arrays.binarySearch(carCodeArray, key)` in my `if` statement. Can you tell me how this is better than the `Set` solution Apart from being more readable?

Comment: It is best only for readability. I think it is the best way to insert a static list of strings in the source code. But if these strings are elsewhere (input? configuration file?) then things change...

Comment: If you were in C# (just now noticed this was a java question), you can get the same readability with a HashSet using a C# collection initializer: ``readonly HashSet<string> carCodeSet = new HashSet() { "FAQ025", "QEF025", ... }``. In my experience, it's better to use the HashSet in almost all cases. Even if you don't think you need the O(log n) look up afforded by a HashSet, you probably do.

Answer (score 11):

Use [Collection.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)).

That reduces your if statement to the following:

```
if ( filterCarCodes.contains(auto.getCarCode()) ){
    //stuff
}
```

You can initialize the Collection once with [Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)), using a `String` array. Then declare it as a static final class variable and you're pretty much set. An alternative is the [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) you described - via `Arrays.asList` you'd have a filled `Collection`, which is one of the constructors for a `HashSet` with contents: `HashSet(Collection<? extends E> c)`. You'll pay for the double conversion, but it should be faster than directly using a `List`.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the algorithm: the codes *work* as a set, so *use* a set.

Your program is then clearer, shorter, and less prone to error. For example, you've inadvertantly (I assume) repeated the first code: harder to do if the codes are all lined up ready to be marched into a set constructor.

You have also repeatedly evaluated `auto.getCarCode()`. The performance hit is no doubt trivial, but you have added a lot of superfluous tokens for the human eye to scan. And how do you make all these condition lines? You copy the first one, and paste, paste, paste. Enough said.

---

How best to do this? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1385698/1562315), suggests (untested - corrections welcome) something like:

```
private static String [] carCodeArray =
  {"FAQ025", "QEF025", "QEF037AB", "FAQ037AB", "FAQ045", 
   "QEF045", "NBEF028", "OPCF028" /* ... */};

private static Set<String> carCodeSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(carCodeArray));

private List<AutoDto> getFilteredAutoList (List<AutoDto> autoList) 
{
    List<AutoDto> filteredAutoList = 
      autoList
      .stream()
      .filter(auto -> carCodeSet.contains(auto.getCarCode())
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return filteredAutoList;
}
```

I've taken the liberty of absorbing the undefined `getAutoListForCoverage()` method into the `autoList` argument.

---

I'm worried that this set of codes is to be burned into the program. It should surely be read in from a configuration file. Is changing the set of codes a program change, with all the testing that entails? I hope not.

---

**Afterthought**

How much more concisely this can be expressed in a functional language. In [Clojure](http://clojure.org/), for example, after

```
(def car-codes #{"FAQ025" "QEF025" "QEF037AB" "FAQ037AB" 
                 "FAQ045" "QEF045" "NBEF028" "OPCF028" #_( ... ))
```

... it can reduce to something like

```
(partial filter (comp car-codes :car-code))
```

... which will work on any collection of things with a `:car-code` field.

Answer (score 6):

Just a note for the curious.

String comparisons are memory comparisons which are slow as you have to check all bytes in the  source operands for a successful or near-successful match. But they can also exit early.

So comparing one \$k\$ character string to \$n\$ strings of \$k\$ characters is anywhere between \$k\$ (match on first) and \$k\cdot n\$ character comparisons (all strings differ on last character). The JIT can optimize memory comparison to use native words instead of chars in loop unrolling.

The array approach suffers from the same problem.

Using a `HashSet` computes the hashes once for all \$n\$ strings as a pre-processing step. Then comparing one \$k\$ character string is equivalent to computing the hash for the string, which is \$\mathcal{O}(k)\$ character operations and then a lookup in the hash table is just an indexing operation, \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$.

So ignoring the setup cost, the runtime improvement would be \$\mathcal{O}(nk) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(k)\$ which seems like a good deal to me.

Answer (score 5):

**Follow Through with the Object Oriented Answers**

Some of the answers I've read call for a `collection`, and implementing a `collection` is exactly the right object oriented answer. BUT it's not the right kind of collection.

**EDIT explicitly address cyclomatic complexity**

- Building data structure is worthwhile. The OP's specific concern is solved with a collection.
- A business-meaningful collection *significantly* reduces a client's workload, e.g. complexity

  - Good adherence to single responsibility principle naturally reduces this metric score. "Good OO manages complexity"
  - a client does not have to parse a generic string to determine if it's "the right kind of string."
  - Client code does not end up as a cascade of nested conditionals in an attempt to assert/ascertain an object's state before calling a method.
- Necessary structure and logic is distributed, becomes less nested, with a naturally lower complexity score.
- The classes below do *far* more validation and error checking yet the cyclomatic complexity is low.

**end edit**

**I humbly suggest a class as shown below.**

- The autoCode is *defined* - that's how I see things - by virtue of containment in a class with business domain meaning. "FAQ025" is just a string. `AutoDto.autoCode` is an Auto Code.
- A generic collection of generic strings falls short. It means nothing. Well, it does mean clients will be forever transforming `string`s to `string collection`s to `AutoCode` objects and back again.
- Consistency. Ease of Maintenance.

  - `string` structures are forced to `AutoCode` objects in the constructors.
  - Now all we have to code for is `AutoCode` objects.
  - Up-front input validation; avoid the "could be null, could be empty" string quandary. We don't blow up just because a reference is null or a string is empty.
- Single Responsibility Principle.

  - The task at hand is a natural fit for a `collection` iteration. And `GetAutoCode()` is in the right class, not a "utility" method floating around in CodeBase Land somewhere.
  - `AutoCode` knows what it's equal to. The client does not have to know `AutoCode` implementation details and does not need to know *how* to test for equality.
- Re-usability. With the  `GetAutoCode` method in the proper class it is by design re-useable.
- DRY, Don't Repeat Yourself. Without the class encapsulation we force *every* client to replicate the data setup.
- Decouple from client code (optional)

  - If the AutoCode values are coming to you in some odd-ball structure *write a separate class* that plucks out the particulars and passes it to `AutoCodeCollection` constructors in the expected form.
  - IMHO it's a judgement call; not really needed unless the odd-ball structure is really complex and we have several classes of this nature.

*Warning this is C#, but you get the idea*

```
public class AutoDto {
    public AutoDto (string aCode) {
        this.autoCode = aCode?? string.Empty; // if aCode is null, use string.Empty;
    }

    protected string autoCode;
    public string GetAutoCode() { return this.autoCode; }

    public override bool Equals (object other) {
        if (other == null) return false;
        if(!other is AutoCode) return false;
        if(this.autoCode == other.autoCode) return true;
        return false;
    }
}

public class AutoDtoCollection : List<AutoDto> {
    public AutoDtoCollection(HashTable autoCodeValues) {}
    public AutoDtoCollection(List<string> autoCodeValues) {}

    // if you must accept a string
    public bool Contains (string testCode) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(testCode)) return false;
        AutoCode tempObject = null;

        // don't implement AutoCode.Equals a second time
        // by violating SRP and making this collection class
        // do the equal-izing.
        foreach (AutoCode mycode in this) {
            tempObject = new AutoCode(testCode);
            if ( mycode.Equals(testCode)) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override bool Contains (object other) {
        if (other == null) return false;

        if (! other is AutoDto) return false;

        // we overrode Equals so we're comparing on the autocode property
        if (this.Contains(other))  return true; 

        return false;
    }

    public override bool Add(string aCode) {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aCode)) return false;
        if(this.Add(new AutoCode(aCode))  // allows duplicates
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}

public class AutoCodeCollectionFactory {
    public AutoCodeCollection Create (HashTable theCodz) {
        foreach (var thing in theCodez {
            // property extraction sound effects here
         }
    }

    public AutoCodeCollection Create (SomeCustomeClass theCodz) {
       // more fussing about to extract what we need
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this.

```
private List<AutoDto> getFilteredAutoList(Collection<String> carCodes) 
{
        List<AutoDto> autoList = getAutoListForCoverage();
        List<AutoDto> filteredAutoList = new ArrayList<AutoDto>();
        for (AutoDto auto : autoList)
        {
            if (carCodes.contains(auto.getCarCode()))
            {
                 filteredAutoList.add(auto);
            }           
        }
        return filteredAutoList;
}
```

You can pass whatever collection of car codes you want to the filtering function. If you want your codes to be unique, use a set, as it does not allow duplicates.

Comment: Sorry, but why would he chose a List over e.G. a HashSet? There's no actual benefit in using a List, except for the fact that you seem to be more comfortable with it...

Comment: I am indeed more comfortable with using a List. A HashSet implements Collection so he may pass a HashSet if  he so desires. But if the application does not require the speed of a HashSet, the benefits brought by it are meaningless and it's just as good as a List. I also find List to be more commonly used, so unless there's an actual need for a HashSet, I'll use List, even if only for the sense of familiarity.

Comment: Keep in mind that Lists allow duplicate items and Sets do not... This is an additional factor you should take into consideration. furthermore using a list is totally overkill, the `List` interface provides an enormous amount of unneeded functionality. OP initially used Set. This has outlined two benefits (no dupes, minimal functionality). Performance isn't even the biggest problem I have with your suggestion.

Comment: I'd argue that code uniqueness shouldn't really be enforced by the underlying collection, but by an outside contract. I can't argue against the minimal functionality, I guess, though I do believe it's not *enormous*.

Comment: Exaggeration is my tool of choice ;) While the uniqueness **should** be enforced by an outside contract, IMO it's the incorrect decision to assume that it were. It's easier to explicitly force the uniqueness by using a set, instead of assuming uniqueness and using a list.

Comment: Your exaggeration is counter-productive and pointless. Case in point, you're trying to convince me a Set is such an amazingly better choice than a List for storing a bunch of strings that get iterated. You seem to not get the point of contracts too. If you're going to just constantly pretend (by not assuming, or rather, not knowing) there is no contract enforced anywhere, then just don't use contracts at all.

Comment: Given that the code in the question doesn't use a `List`, this answer needs a better explanation of why to use a `List` over the solutions attempted in the question.

Comment: @AlexM. One can programmatically ensure uniqueness of elements in a `List`, but when any developer is looking at `List` and `Set` instances, it is clear that the latter can only have unique elements. That's the whole point of contracts isn't it, to have a clearer method signature `Set<?> getUniqueElements()` instead of `List<?> getUniqueElements()`, generally speaking?

Comment: Very well, got the point. Updated the answer.